# Can I use requests for web scraping in python for request URL with POST method

Tags: python, python-requests

I tried to use requests in python to web *scrape* this page:

On web page https://www.otpbanka.hr/tecajna-lista there is Request URL: https://www.otpbanka.hr/otp/ajax/exchange but Method is POST.

[image]

In dev tools in Response tab I can see JSON code for the content but is there a way I can read it in Python?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: @Xiddoc - question about using requests in Python

Comment: Read *what* in Python exactly? The response body? The contents of your DevTools window? What code have you written so far? What HTTP library have you elected to use? It’s not possible to give you any concrete, actionable advice without including this detail, at a minimum. [ask]

Comment: Did you mean:
Can I use `requests` to request POST method for web scraping in Python?
If yes, then
`requests.post("https://example.com", {"data": data})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a quick look on the request, there seems to be a form data that is also to be passed in order for server to respond with a desired result, else it simply returns nothing (no body).

Try:

```
import requests

query_data = {
    "q1": "latest",
    "q2": "OTP",
    "q3": '',
    "q4": 'DISPLAY'
}

response = requests.post('https://www.otpbanka.hr/otp/ajax/exchange', data = query_data)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print(response.json())
else:
    print(response.status_code)
```